# Compositor connection lines

Tags: workflow, compositing-nodes

Sometimes curved or fluid connector lines are tiring to work with in a complex node setup. Is there a way to change the shape to a more straight line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, open up your *User Preferences > Themes > Node Editor* and set the **Noodle curving** to **0**.

[image]

If you want to **reset** it, default value is **6**.